Is there a calculus equivalent to $\Pi$ like how integration is similar to $\Sigma$?
There's a lot of similarities between integration and summation.  I've been pretty comfortable thinking of integration as an "infinite" variant of summation.
I've recently been pondering whether there are other calculus of infinitesimals operators.  Is there anything that is equivalent to repeated product operations ($\Pi$).
As an extreme version of a "no" answer, I am curious if there are any ways to show that integration and differentiation are "special" with respect to the structure of real numbers, showing that other operators just aren't meaningful.

You can turn products into sums using $\log$

There is a multiplicative version of the integral known as the "product integral" or "geometric integral". It is just the exponential of the ordinary integral of the logarithm.

There is (somewhat)! So, formally, let's define the Riemann integral: we say
$$
\int_a^b f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x = I \tag{$\ast$}
$$
to mean the following:

Let $P := \{x_i\}_{i=0}^n$ where $a =: x_0 < x_1 < \cdots < x_n := b$ be a partition of $[a,b]$.
Let $\Xi := \{\xi_i\}_{i=1}^n$ be a collection of tag points, in that $\xi_i \in [x_{i-1},x_i]$.
Define the Riemann sum of $f$ w.r.t. $P,\Xi$ by
$$
R(f,P,\Xi) := \sum_{i=1}^n f(\xi_i) \Delta x_i
$$
Here, $\Delta x_i = x_i - x_{i-1}$.
We let $\|P\| := \max \Delta x_i$ be the norm of the partition.
Finally, we say that $(\ast)$ holds if: for every $\varepsilon > 0$, there is a $\delta > 0$ such that, for any partition with $\|P\| < \delta$, and for any collection of tags $\Xi$ respecting that partition, we have
$$
|R(f,P,\Xi) - I| < \varepsilon
$$
We may even write
$$
\lim_{\|P\| \to 0} R(f,P,\Xi) =: \int_a^b f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x
$$


... okay so that's a mouthful. But it's necessary to establish what the product analogue is. I'll forego some of the details, but the idea is you want to transform the Riemann sum into a "Riemann product" if you will:
$$
\prod_{i=1}^n f(\xi_i) \Delta x_i
$$
This object does not really exist or pique our interest. Consider the case of an equispaced partition, so that
$$
\Delta x_i = \frac{b-a}{n}
$$
You can see that, for $n$ very large, the product overall goes to zero.

So instead what we can have is
$$
G(f,P,\Xi) := \prod_{i=1}^n f(\xi_i)^{\Delta x_i}
$$
We define, then,
$$
\lim_{\|P\| \to 0} G(f,P,\Xi) =: \prod_a^b f(x)^{\mathrm{d}x}
$$
to be the geometric integral of $f$. This ultimately does not necessarily interest us too much beyond some convenient applications since
$$
\prod_a^b  f(x)^{\mathrm{d}x}
= \exp \left( \int_a^b \ln(f(x)) \, \mathrm{d}x \right)
$$
Sometimes we write
$$
\int f(x)^{\mathrm{d}x}
$$
instead as the product integral.

We could rescue our failed attempt with a small modification, to get Volterra's geometric integral,
$$
V(f,P,\Xi) := \prod_{i=1}^n \Big( 1 + f(\xi_i) \Delta x_i \Big)
$$
with the usual construction of a limit for the final integral. This equivalence holds:
$$
\lim_{\|P\| \to 0} V(f,P,\Xi) =: \prod_a^b (1 + f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x) = \exp\left( \int_a^b f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x \right)
$$

Wikipedia has some more information, e.g. a bigeometric integral,
$$
\prod_a^b f(x)^{\mathrm{d} \ln x} = \exp\left(\int_{\ln(a)}^{\ln(b)} \ln f(e^x) \,\mathrm{d}x\right)
$$
Some more details on these three formulations and basic results can be found there. Some integral rules and such can also be found here.
